# file in the controller says undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble while uploading a file. I have created one service:

```
angular
.module('app')
.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}}]);
```

then i have a directive:

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};}]);
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ' );
    console.dir(file);
    var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
};
```

HTML:

```
Browse <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

As you can see i am using console.log in the controller and what i am having is

> file is undefined

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
    .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
scope: {
        percent: "=fileModel"

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;
scope.$watch('percent', function(value) {
console.log(value)
});

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};}]);
```

check the console value inside the percentage watch once you upload file

Comment: It says 'undefined'!

Comment: create a fiddle or plunker so that easy to fix